# Структура базы данных для проекта

Tags: структуры-данных, база-данных

Всем привет!

Давно не писал, решил вспомнить, как это, и сразу вопрос в лоб, даже не вопрос, а хотелось бы рассуждений на тему структуры и реализации таблиц(ы).

Дано:
 1. Есть данные - это по большому счету перечисление символов по порядку, а-ля брутфорс (от 0 до, скажем, ZZZZZZ).
 2. Набор включает в себя цифры и буквы ENG алфавита большие и маленькие.

Варианты решения:
Т.к. мы не можем с уверенностью сказать, что мы знаем, какая последовательность будет, допустим, у 10000 элемента, поскольку нам нужно будет перебрать все варианты, запишем все эти варианты в таблицу БД (id, var):

```
id var
 1  0
 2  1
 3  2
 4  3
 .  ...
 n ZZZZZZ
```

Допустим, получилось около 15 миллионов записей.

У нас есть пользователи, которым мы будем раздавать эти записи, понятное дело, что будет связь uid > id, это понятно.

Вопрос заключается в том, чтобы не заполнять таблицу сразу всеми имеющимися записями, а заполнять её по ходу, но не перебирая все возможные варианты.

Или же наоборот вариант с первичными данными лучший?

Может тут случиться так, что 15 миллионов не хватит, тогда мы увеличиваем длину на 1, было 6 - станет 7, кол-во записей возрастает, но таблицу нужно дополнить новыми, вопрос как если мы не знаем, что за чем идет?

2 эти данные можно разнести на несколько таблиц по 15 миллионов записей, к примеру, а потом на разные сервера.

Есть идеи, как можно реализовать?

**//upd** можно, конечно, вставлять данные на лету и проверять их на существование в таблице, но опять-таки, на первых порах - это будет быстро, а дальше? Если будет 10 таблиц по 10 миллионов записей?
Индексы - да, но как понять, в какой таблице искать.

**//upd**
и все равно, как узнать следующий элемент из набора символов то? Чтобы не плодить сразу таблицу со значениями? про 256 немного не понял, и ссылка мне не особо помогла.

Comment: У вас не будет полного перебора вариантов?

Comment: @mantigatos ну я ведь написал, что есть 2 варианта решения, нужно выбрать какой-то.

Либо заранее сделать +100500 миллионов таких записей, но как вариант они могут кончиться, либо придумать, как их в процессе дописывать.

Примерно 6 часов вставляются 10 миллионов записей у меня на домашнем стареньком сервере.

Занимают примерно 450-500Мб.
Делать 10 таблиц - это примерно 40-60Гб места - которое сразу будет забито, но отчасти решит вопрос, но что делать, если записи кончатся? Опять перебивать все таблицы? Нет, вариант плохой, нужно решение какое-то.

Comment: А как раздавать-то записи пользователям будете? Если первому пользователю - "1", второму "2" и т.д., то чем не "очень длинная арифметика"? )) По последней записи всегда можно будет узнать следующее число - всего-то +1 сделать. Соответственно, и 354901-ую запись легко будет получить (основы арифметики, надеюсь, напоминать не надо? )))

Comment: @ворон 

Если бы все правильно сначала читали суть вопроса и только потом отвечали - было бы очень здорово.

Есть данные - это по большому счету перечисление символов по порядку, а-ля брутфорс (от 0 до, скажем, ZZZZZZ). 


ZZZZZZ - это 6 букв Z. Я ведь не написал, что от 0 до 999999.

Прочитай еще раз, что дано. С цифрами все просто, а с цифрами и буквами? А если туда добавить хотя бы один символ ".", допустим?

Comment: @Shrek, я понял, что дано. Я не понял, как вы это будете пользователям выдавать. Если рандомом - это одно, мой способ не пойдет. Если же в порядке возрастания - совсем другое. В последнем случае со строкой (любой строкой) можно работать как с числом - кто мешает использовать 256-ричную систему счисления?

Comment: Нет, не рандомно, по порядку все.Но есть вариант того что мне нужно будет заранее забить какое-то значение в бд, допустим "xxx" и оно должно отработать корректно.

И как это выглядит? О_о я про 256 систему? Просто как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @Shrek, сразу подумал про 36-ричную систему (учитывая цифры + буквы англ алфавита). Вычислять на ходу одно удовольствие, зная предыдущий всегда можешь узнать следующий. Хранить алгоритмическую последовательность это глупо ж. Приоткрой чуть-чуть завесу, чтобы понятнее было, пока читал, весь мозг сломал в предположениях, что же в итоге хочешь получить.

Comment: @stck в общем, нужно хранить такие нехитрые вещи.

Итак по порядку:  
есть набор для формирования списка 0-9-a-Z[.,!@#$%] символы тоже могут быть.
Нужно иметь возможность записывать следующую комбинацию в бд и привязывать её к какому-то пользователю.

Также существует вероятность того, что какому-то пользователю можно выдать запись Zhei45 - допустим, но она будет записана 100 позицией в таблицу.
И как вы предлагаете использовать другие системы счисления для подобного решения задачи? Конвертация не желательна, т.к. поиск будет по Zhei45 таким записям.

Comment: @Shrek, 256-чная система так и будет выглядеть: 123sdf%^&$324h... Вас же не смущает 16-чная система? Более того - вы часто пользуетесь вариацией 60-чной системы (вспомните про часы).

Никто не заставляет конвертировать числа в другие системы исчисления. Вы же не конвертируете 10-чные числа в двоичные? ) В базе пусть это будет строкой, а в коде вы можете работать как с числом через какую-либо библиотеку. [Здесь](http://pastebin.com/8hN1zAAf) халтурная версия длинной арифметики (писать было лень, поэтому это ОЧЕНЬ халтурная версия)))

Answer (score 1):

Используйте хеши. Перебирайте данные на лету, в БД храните пару хеш-строка. 
У вас всегда будет однозначное соответвие сроки и хеша, поиск по хешу при индексе на столбец с хешом будет проходить за log(n), что достаточно быстро.

Comment: Это не ответ. А как дописывать новые данные?
Плюс ко всему - это немыслимое увеличение размера БД, хеши весят немало. И тем более хешей тоже много, какой тут будет использовать правильнее...

Comment: А вы уверены в однозначном соответствии хеша и строки? Вы про коллизии не слышали никогда? Уже на небольшом наборе данных с большой долей вероятностью будут наблюдаться коллизии, а тут даже на наборе [A-Z]{6} будет 26^6 >= 2^24 различных вариантов, т.е. вероятность коллизий резко увеличивается.